# How to execute a .bat file with java program?

Tags: java, ant

How to execute a .bat file with java program?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this? Not that it matters as its not possible.

Comment: This is bizarre. It's like converting an apple to an orange.

Comment: are you a project manager with a budget problem ?

Comment: MAybe you post the .bat file. It *might* be trivial or simple.

Comment: Is the batch file running a Java program through command line? Or is it something you want to port? As it stands, your question is really unclear and broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bat` files cannot be converted directly to `jar` files.

But you can implement bat file logic in a java application, using, for instance [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) and when it is compiled, [package it as a jar file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the rationale behind the question, the reason why they want you to do it ? Creating a jar requires development in java.

I think you need more information how the final application will be deployed. They probably have additional requirements which made them decide it could no longer be developed in a shell scripting language but requires a real programming language.

Make sure you understand the 'why?' before thinking about the 'how?'.

good luck